# Trusted Web Activity for PWA in different sessions

Tags: android, session, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I have a website for which i create two android Apps using Trusted Web Activity. When user login using App1 it it also show me login in App2. Is there any solution so that both Apps behave as a separate App? i want to use both Apps side by side.

Answer (score 2):

Opening two TWA application is similar as opening two tabs in chrome browser.

It's is also possible that if ur logged in with Android chrome browser, ur also logged in with twa applications as well.

Browser's  Local storage and cookies are all shared by chrome browser, pwa and twa.

Only thing unique is tab session.

Whenever you open a TWA application a single chrome tab is opened and when you click on any link you are still in same tab, so to achieve your goal you have to write you logic according to this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have used this code 
CustomTabsSession session = client.newSession(null, SESSION_ID); i used SESSION_ID different in both Apps i.e SESSION_ID = 1 and 2. But still it behave same if i login from App1 is shows me login in App2

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that in IOS - the browser and PWA are completely separate (and therefore possibly App1 and App2 (I'm not an IOS user)). See https://www.netguru.com/codestories/how-to-share-session-cookie-or-state-between-pwa-in-standalone-mode-and-safari-on-ios which talks about how **TO** share between but therefore clearly shows IOS is different to Android/Chrome.